# calling prototyped function in javascript without creating an object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to call a prototyped function from another javascript file but it doesn't seem to work.

BuddyList.js :

```
function BuddyList(){ .. }

BuddyList.prototype = {
    addBuddy : function(buddyName){...}
}
```

UserOptions.js:

```
function UserOptions(){
....
BuddyList.addBuddy(username);
}
```

I get an error stating that BuddyList does not have a method called addBuddy

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the .prototype method.  Since everything in JS is an object, you can simply extend BuddyList with a new function:

```
function BuddyList(){
     // do whatever
}

BuddyList.addBuddy = function(username){
      // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.addBuddy` is defined on objects that are constructed from the `BuddyList` constructor.

You can not call a method of an object like you are trying to do.

You might want to create it as a "static" function

`BuddyList.addBuddy = function(buddyName) { ... }`

You can then call it from the prototype aswell

```
BuddyList.prototype.addBuddy = function(buddyName) {
    BuddyList.addBuddy.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

You would need to check for any references to a `BuddyList` object inside the `addBuddy` function though.

Remember `BuddyList` is an object constructor. Calling the `addBuddy` method on the constructor doesn't make sense. I think you actaully want to do this

```
buddyList = new BuddyList;
buddyList.append(someBuddy);
```

In theory if there's only ever one BuddyList then you may want to look for

`BuddyList = new BuddyList;`

That will overwrite your constructor with an object inherited from the constructor.

You can always call the `addBuddy` method directly without an object through the prototype as follows:

`BuddyList.prototype.addBudy.call(this, someBuddy)`

It really depends on what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a prototype function until and unless you create an instance for the object or function. So instead of

```
BuddyList.addBuddy(buddyName)
```

you have to write

```
new BuddyList().addBuddy(buddyName)
```